# Gitlab webui ask password after settings password via gitlab-rails

Tags: passwords, gitlab

After the installation of gitlab i use gitlab-rails to change root password but the webinterface still asks to set a password.
If i change the password on the WebUI i can use gitlab-rails to change password.
So i used

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'admin@local.host')
user.password = 'secret_pass'
user.password_confirmation = 'secret_pass'
user.save
```

or

```
gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = 'nonstandardpassword'in gitlab.rb
gitlab-rake gitlab:setup
```

Do you have an idea that how i can  initalize first root password without the gui ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD=<your_pass> GITLAB_ROOT_EMAIL=<your_mail>`

Hope this helpful for you :)