# Gitlab - Random string appearing as URL

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

It seems some random string appears as a URL whenever I try to edit any runner in Gitlab installed on Docker. The URL is something like:

http://67bee76f5734/groups/docker/-/runners/2/edit

Why do I see 67bee76f5734 instead of my domain name? Also the runner internally tries to access the same url which doesn't exist.

Comment: Please provide the code you’re describing, ideally as a [mre]

Comment: I have managed to get a solution. In gitlab.rb file you have to specify external_url config parameter to a url accessible by gitlab

Answer (score 0):

> I have managed to get a solution. In gitlab.rb file you have to specify external_url config parameter to a url accessible by gitlab

Yes, you're right.

For future internet surfers. In the [docker compose file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose).

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: 'docker.io/gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://target.ip.address:8929'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
    ports:
      - '8929:8929'
      - '2224:22'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '512m'

networks:
    default:
        name: gitlab-nw
```

You've to provide `external_url 'http://target.ip.address:8929'` under `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG`.

Additionally, if you run into root-password issue with GitLab-CE, checkout: [gitlab initial root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062065/gitlab-initial-root-password)